# elasticsearch: where is bootstrap.system_call_filter set?

Tags: elasticsearch, seccomp

elasticsearch 6.4.2 on Centos 7.5

I need to turn off bootstrap.system_call_filter (because it is preventing startup, for reasons I do not understand, [outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53047269/147637))

When I add:
system_call_filter=false

to jvm.options, elastic doesn't start at all.

Where is this set?

Answer (score 1):

It goes into `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml`

```
bootstrap.system_call_filter: false
```

Not clearly documented....